# VS2010 C++ Debug managed (C++/CLI) DLL

Tags: c++, debugging, dll, c++-cli

I have currently two projects inside my solution. 
Both are 64bit projects.

One is a native C++ console app, the other is a C++/CLI DLL. I want to debug (step through) the DLL from my native C++ console app. This won't work though and I dont know why.

Can anyone help me with that?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: set Debugger Type to `Mixed`  in debugging tab of C+/CLI project properties.

Comment: I did. Setting this only for C++/CLI did nothing. Both projects with the setting you suggested resulted in a "no source available" message.

Comment: Did you try also this: `Options->Debugging->General->Suppress jit optimization on module load`?

Comment: Yes. It was already checked. Checking/unchecking did not help.